# Создать пользовательский элемент упарвления

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, usercontrol

Есть кнопка

```
<UserControl x:Class="WCL1.RoundButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WCL1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button Height="{Binding ElementName=RoundButton, Path=Height}" Width="{Binding ElementName=RoundButton, Path=Wight}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="controlLayout">
                        <Ellipse x:Name="buttonSurface" Fill="LightBlue"></Ellipse>
                        <Label x:Name="buttonCaption" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               FontSize="20" Content="{Binding ElementName=RoundButton, Path=Text}"></Label>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

---

```
public partial class RoundButton : UserControl
    {
        static DependencyProperty TextProperty;
        static DependencyProperty FillProperty;
       // static DependencyProperty HeightProperty;
        //static DependencyProperty FontSizeProperty;
        //static DependencyProperty FillProperty;
        //static DependencyProperty FillProperty;
        //static DependencyProperty FillProperty;
        //static DependencyProperty FillProperty;
        public RoundButton()
        {
            TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(RoundButton),null);
            FillProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Fill", typeof(string), typeof(RoundButton), null);
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }
        public Brush Fill
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(FillProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FillProperty, value); }
        }
        private static void OnContentChanged(DependencyObject sender,
            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            RoundButton rb = (RoundButton)sender;
        }
     }
```

Подключаю библиотеку к проекту и хочу использовать эту кнопку

```
<myDll:RoundButton Height="30" Width="30"></myDll:RoundButton>
```

Но на все свойства ноль реакции, а на значение Fill вообще говорит, что оно не допустимо,а text "свойство text уже зарегистрировано в RoundButton" и выдает ошибку.

Как сделать этот UserControl максимально похожим на обычный элемент Button?

P.S.

Было решено отказаться от UserControl, а использовать настраиваемую библиотеку элементов управления

```
namespace WCCL1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Выполните шаги 1a или 1b, а затем 2, чтобы использовать этот пользовательский элемент управления в файле XAML.
    ///
    /// Шаг 1a. Использование пользовательского элемента управления в файле XAML, существующем в текущем проекте.
    /// Добавьте атрибут XmlNamespace в корневой элемент файла разметки, где он 
    /// будет использоваться:
    ///
    ///     xmlns:MyNamespace="clr-namespace:WCCL1"
    ///
    ///
    /// Шаг 1б. Использование пользовательского элемента управления в файле XAML, существующем в другом проекте.
    /// Добавьте атрибут XmlNamespace в корневой элемент файла разметки, где он 
    /// будет использоваться:
    ///
    ///     xmlns:MyNamespace="clr-namespace:WCCL1;assembly=WCCL1"
    ///
    /// Потребуется также добавить ссылку из проекта, в котором находится файл XAML,
    /// на данный проект и пересобрать во избежание ошибок компиляции:
    ///
    ///     Щелкните правой кнопкой мыши нужный проект в обозревателе решений и выберите
    ///     "Добавить ссылку"->"Проекты"->[Поиск и выбор проекта]
    ///
    ///
    /// Шаг 2)
    /// Теперь можно использовать элемент управления в файле XAML.
    ///
    ///     <MyNamespace:RoundButton/>
    ///
    /// </summary>
    public class RoundButton : Control
    {
        string dText = "RounButton";
        Brush dFill = Brushes.Blue;
        public string Text
        {
            get { return dText; }
            set { dText = value; }
        }
        public Brush Fill
        {
            get { return dFill; }
            set { dFill = value; }
        }
        static RoundButton()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(RoundButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(RoundButton)));
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WCCL1">


    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:RoundButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:RoundButton}">
                    <Grid x:Name="controlLayout">
                        <Ellipse x:Name="buttonSurface" Fill="{Binding Fill}"></Ellipse>
                        <Label x:Name="buttonCaption" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Content="{Binding Text}"></Label>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Как теперь подключить эту библиотеку и правильно ли я все забиндил?

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему, вам не нужен не `UserControl`, а обыкновенный стиль с переопределением `Template`'а.

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="RoundButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid x:Name="controlLayout">
                    <Ellipse x:Name="buttonSurface" Fill="LightBlue"/>
                    <ContentPresenter
                        TextBlock.FontSize="20" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Применять так:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource RoundButtonStyle}">
    Test
</Button>
```

---

Ошибка в вашем коде — вы используете `ElementName=RoundButton`, но не определяете элемент с таким именем. Кроме того, вы должны вызывать `DependencyProperty.Register` в статическом конструкторе, иначе получите ошибку, когда попробуете использовать контрол во второй раз.

---

В новом коде ошибки:

1. Вы в `RoundButton` определяете не `DependencyProperty`, а обыкновенные свойства. Это неправильно.
2. Вместо `{Binding Fill}` нужно `{TemplateBinding Fill}`, и то же для `Text`. В остальном должно работать, по идее.

Но если ваша цель всё же быть похожим на нормальную кнопку, лучше попробовать просто поменять стиль (если можно, даже не менять `Template`).

Comment: Я решил использовать не UserControl, a сделать библиотеку Custom Control Library. Но все равно не понимаю, как все настроить и подключить ее.

Comment: И где Вы определили элемент с именем?

Comment: @SanychGoilo: Обновил ответ. // Объявлять элемент с именем не обязательно, можно вместо этого использовать `TemplateBinding`.

Comment: Как потом подключить dll в xaml?

Comment: @SanychGoilo: В каком смысле «подключить DLL»? Вы имеете в виду `xmlns:lib="clr-namespace:WCCL1;assembly=WCCL1"`?

Comment: Вроде так она подключается, а как потом вызвать правильно элемент? Просто пишет, что RoundButton нет в WCCL1

Comment: @SanychGoilo: А вы подключили DLL как reference в проекте? Если да, то должно быть просто `<lib:RoundButton Text="ABC"/>`. (Это если вы вызываете из **другой** DLL или EXE.)